# If a 'many-to-many' field is added to directus_users

Tags: directus

Firstly, I love the Directus CMS and I chose to implement it on my new project. So far I am just loving it.

Now I have this issue where the user create functionality was added, with email verification etc all was good. Until I added a new o2m field in the directus_fields & proper relations were made. Works well in the admin panel, but while I want any user to signup from frontend the api now throws error code 3, 401 Unauthorized request. I tried all the permissions, for the junction collection, the field one collection and also the directus_users collection.

PS: It works back normal when I tried deleting the field from the directus_fields table. Thats why I am actually guessing that the issue is from the relations related permissions. And the relation works well and fine from the admin panel.

So again my question is, if an o2m 'many-to-many' field is added to 'directus_users' collection what are the permissions, alterations required for public user/create functionality. The field is not marked as required.

I am using version 8.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I made a temporary solution.

Removed the o2m field from the directus_users table, instead created a new collection containing the additional users_data and created the many-to-many field in it so the registration is secure and also doesn't require to tamper the directus_users table. All I had to do in addition was to modify the extra request parameters from the frontend.

Although, I still believe my question is a valid one.